# How to access the current user within a Notification?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

On the Laravel docs, it states:

> **Using The Notification Facade**
>
> Alternatively, you may send
> notifications via the Notification facade. This is useful primarily
> **when you need to send a notification to multiple notifiable entities**
> such as a collection of users. To send notifications using the facade,
> pass all of the notifiable entities and the notification instance to
> the send method:

```
Notification::send($users, new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

So I am doing this within my controller:

```
public function index()
{
  $subscribers = Subscribers::all();
  
  Notification::send($subscribers, new NewVacancy($subscribers));
}
```

And here is my Notification class

```
class NewVacancy extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable;

public $subscriber; 

public function __construct( $subscribers)
{
    $this->subscriber = $subscribers;
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
 
  return (new MailMessage)->view(
    'mail.new-vacancy', 
    ['uuid' => $this->subscriber->uuid]// This fails as $subscriber is a collection
  );
}

....
```

The problem is that within the `NewVacancy` class, the `$subscriber` that is passed in is a full collection of all subscribers and not the individual notification being sent.

Now I know I could do a loop over `$subscribers` and fire the `Notification::send()` each time but that defeats the point of using facade to begin with.

The general goal is to send emails to all `$subscribers` with the ability to pass in unique subscriber data using a blade template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out you can access the current user via the `$notifiable` entity thats passed into the `toMail()` method.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{

  return (new MailMessage)->view(
    'mail.new-vacancy', 
    ['uuid' => $notifiable->uuid]
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that $notifiable represents the user object which is getting notified.

```
$user_id = $notifiable->id;
```

Comment: This 'answer' is redundant as it's duplicating my own answer that's accepted post in April...